# How to ssh into an AWS EC2 instance with Remmina

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to replace putty with Remmina as I need to log into several instances and I get an "Enter private key passphrase", even though I had not set one up for the key. I use the same params as in putty, ec2-user, public dnsand the ppk keyfile.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Name Profile** 
   (example: AWS EC2 Instance)
2. **PROTOCOL:** SSH - Secure Shell
3. **Post Command:** /path/to/file -i "file.pem"
   (example: /home/$USER/Desktop -i "ec2privatekey.pem")
   *SSH [-i identity_file]*
4. **User name:** [EC2_USER]
5. **Authentication type:** SSH identity file
6. **Identity File:** *CHECK* Box & *ATTACH* file.pem
7. ***Save & Connect***

[REMMINA ec2 SSH AWS Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpXMp.jpg)

Comment: Image link is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I use the same params as in putty, ec2-user, public dns **and the ppk keyfile**.

Putty PPK files use a file format specific to putty (and certain other programs like WinSCP). Unix-based ssh clients typically use a different key file format compatible with the OpenSSH software. If you want to use your existing key with this Remmina utility, you'll need to convert it from the Putty format to the OpenSSH format.

This process is documented in the [Putty puttygen documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-conversions). On a PC, open puttygen, load the key in question, then select Conversions->Export to export it in an OpenSSH-compatible format. OpenSSH private key filenames commonly have names like "id_rsa" with no extension. But this isn't important--you could name the file whatever you like.

Alternately, you could create a new key on your Linux system, install the public part on the server, and use that.

[Putty has a page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/key-formats-natively.html) explaining why it uses a different key format, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Post Command: ssh -i "/home/x/.ssh/id_ed25519"` did it for me.