# Issue with Tectia SFTP referencing ppk file but still prompting for a password

Tags: sftp

I have been tasked with swapping out PSFTP for Tectia SFTPG3 ftp client for a large number of ETL jobs that run unattended from the command line. We have some SFTP sites that we authenticate to by referencing a PPK file with the -i option. In these cases, we do not use a password. So using PSFTP the command is something like...

```
psftp.exe -i "C:\somepath\somesshkeyfile.PPK" someusername@somesftpsite.com
```

This works. If the key does not exist in the cache, we get get a response asking us if we want to cache it and our code responds to that. When I try the same thing with Tectia's SFTPG3.exe I still get prompted for a password which we do not have and does not exist. I have tried it with the -i option and their -K option. Same thing happens either way. Yesterday morning I emailed out contact at Tectia, and yesterday afternoon I copied the info email address on their website. I still have not heard back. Neither of these appear to work as expected.

```
sftpg3.exe -i "C:\somepath\somesshkeyfile.PPK" someusername@somesftpsite.com
sftpg3.exe -K "C:\somepath\somesshkeyfile.PPK" someusername@somesftpsite.com
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39174835/13317

Comment: The Tectia contact replied today. Said the ppk files were likely in the wrong format and needed to be regenerated with one of their command line tools. If that does not work out there is a debug to run their sftpg3 executable in.